# How to fix 'ImportError: No module named search' error in django 1.8

Tags: python, django, python-import

I'm get an error when running `"python manage.py makemigrations"` command in putty.

```
from dslam.views import *
  File "/opt/PortMan/portman_web/dslam/views.py", line 16, in <module>
    from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector
ImportError: No module named search
```

When running `pip install django-contrib-postgres` command, I'm get this message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: equirement already satisfied: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (0.0.1)
```

Comment: which django version ?

Comment: Hi, django version is 1.8,

Answer (score 2):

`pip install django-contrib-postgres` installs [this](https://pypi.org/project/django-contrib-postgres/), which seems to be a stand-alone extract of `django.contrib.postgres`, which is usually part of a complete `django` installation. According to the [README](https://github.com/sorl/django-contrib-postgres) it does not provide `django.contrib.postgres` and also shouldn't as it is not a complete `django installation`. I recommend to just install `django`:

```
pip uninstall  django-contrib-postgres
pip install django
```

Then you should be able to do `from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector` just fine

Answer (score 1):

`django.contrib.postgres.search` was added in Django 1.10, so you can't use it with `django-contrib-postgres`, which is a backport from Django 1.9.

Note that Django 1.8 has been end of life for years and is insecure. You should upgrade to the latest Django 1.11.X LTS, or even better, upgrade to Python 3 and the latest Django 2.2.X LTS.